# Vitest gives no output

Tags: unit-testing, testing, vitest

I'm new to testing and im trying to write some unit tests for my Vue app. The problem is that vitest givesno output and I cant figure out what is wrong. Any help would be apriciated.

```
describe('UserForm', () => {
    it('renders component properly', async () => {
        const viewId = "123"
        
        render(UserForm, {
            props: {
                open: true
            }
        })

        const view = await screen.findByText('Kontrahent')
    
        expect(view.id).toBe(viewId)
    })

})
```

I run the test with this command
`vitest --environment jsdom`

Comment: I also started having this issue with Vitest a few days ago, I wonder if it's a problem with Vitest itself and not our configs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do something like:

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

// in the describe
const wrapper = mount(Login, {
  props: {
    open: true
  },
});

it("mounts the component", () => {
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("Kontrahent");
});
```